# Remove JSON keys with wildcards from a MySQL field

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database

I have a MySQL 8.0.20 database with a table that describes metadata about uploaded image files.  One column contains a JSON object with a whole bunch of auto-generated data that I'm trying to clean up.

This JSON object *sometimes* contains *one or more* variable key names that match a specific pattern.  Something like

```
{
 "image_name": "P10043983",
 "image_size": "60138",
 "image_original_exifdata": "{
   'FileName':'P10043983.jpg',
   'MimeType':'image/jpeg',
   'UndefinedTag:0xA435':'\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'
 }"
}
```

That `UndefinedTag:0xA435` (with many permutations) is the problem.  It's referring to various image Exif details like lens type, GPS data, etc.  It's stuff that I'm not interested in and that these cameras mostly don't provide, so I've ended up with a table full of long strings of useless characters just taking up space.  I want those JSON fields gone for performance and cleanliness.

Is there a way to run a SQL query that would use wildcards or regular expressions to find (and, ideally, remove) all of these pesky variable keys?  I'd like to avoid manually making a list of all of the possible "UndefinedTag" keys to search against, and I also didn't like the results when I just treated the whole thing as a string and did REGEXP_REPLACE calls (it sometimes left trailing commas that broke my JSON and were difficult for me to avoid/resolve).

I know some of the JSON functions like `JSON_SEARCH()` accept wildcards, but it explicitly says the search path can't *end* in a wildcard (so no `UndefinedTag:0x**` allowed).  Many of the functions I'm after (e.g., `JSON_REMOVE()`) don't accept wildcards at all.  Hell, I've even had trouble finding *known* keys, and I suspect that silly colon in the key name might have something to do with it.

So, how can I clean up my table and remove the many forms of this *UndefinedTag* problem?  Maybe it's easier to just go back to the regex_replace plan and deal instead with the trailing commas?

Comment: *I know some of the JSON functions like JSON_SEARCH() accept wildcards, but it explicitly says the search path can't end in a wildcard (so no UndefinedTag:0x\*\* allowed).* You must search not by key but by value (which allows pattern chars) and retrieve the path then test the path against the pattern and delete the element by matched found path.

Comment: But I don't know the values to search for, and they are different for each row and key.  There's currently about 10,000 such rows.  Sometimes it's like 300 LF characters, sometimes it's an array of integers, sometimes a string describing the camera.

Comment: Does you have a patters for KEY, not for a value? If so you must use JSON_KEYS() and get an array with existing keys. Then you must parse it to separate elements using JSON_TABLE(). Then each separate key must be checked against the pattern. Then use matched keynames for deletion.

Comment: An option that can give you some ideas [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbec7fab59629345b057cf4e9af72315).